# GWT inject jQuery script after page load

Tags: gwt

I have html page with script file custom.js that is bootstrap for GWT

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <!-- -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="login/login.nocache.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="common/js/custom.js"></script>
</head> 
        <div id="gwt-inject-place"/> 
</html>
```

And that is ok, all works fine.
But in custom.js there is function that I need to fire after login/login.nocache.js inject some html in `<div id="gwt-inject-place"/>`. Normally custom.js is somehow run before injection take place.

So what should I do to inject JavaScript jquery file?

```
alert('global');
jQuery(document).ready(function () 
{
 alert('inner');
}
```

This inject custom.js but only `global alert` shows.

```
public void onModuleLoad(){
  RootPanel.get("gwt-inject-place").add(view);
  ScriptInjector.fromUrl("../common/js/custom.js").inject();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From Google Docs :

```
<script src="js-url"/>
```

Automatically injects the external JavaScript file located at the location specified by src. See automatic resource inclusion for details.

So, You have to place the injection on `module.gwt.xml`

further Info: [Link](http://www.gwtapps.com/doc/html/com.google.gwt.doc.DeveloperGuide.Fundamentals.Modules.ModuleXml.html)